# Is my motherboard OK after accidentally putting a case screw in a non-case screw hole?

Tags: motherboard

I was building my first computer, and I accidentally put a case screw into another screw's spot to secure the motherboard. However, I cannot get it out. It makes weird "clicking" screws every 1 turn or so and I'm afraid to mess around with it. I cannot remove it. **How do I remove this case screw?** I want to get it out because it puts unnecessary tension on the motherboard (not too much but still...) I also, while trying to get it out, I bent a capacitor a little (30 degrees about) but it's still intact. I ended up bending it back. **Should my motherboard be okay?** It didn't damage the PCB at all except a hairline scratch. **How do I get the screw out?**

Comment: You need to remove it.  It can indeed cause a short.  We can't tell you if your motherboard will be "ok"

Comment: Use a screwdriver with a magnetic.  You got it in there you can get it out.  electricity and metal in places where they should not causes shorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motherboard screws are usually being screwed into spacers that in turn are screwed into the case:

[image]

The case screw has a different thread that the motherboard one, so by screwing it into the spacer you basically stripped the thread.

So to get it out you need to get to the spacer and hold it (perhaps with a side wrench of the small size) while attempting to unscrew it.

The other option is to remove ALL screws except yours and try to remove the board with the spacer still attached and remove if afterwards

Answer (score 2):

After letting off some steam, I realised the standoff and screw were "stuck" together; if you moved one you moved the other no matter what. I unscrewed all the other screws and I was able to unscrew the whole motherboard [with the standoff and screw still attached to it] and with pliers and a screwdriver I was able to disassemble it all. Next time, I'll read the manual!!!